# Event equaling the impossible event with probability $1$

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question regarding events with probability $1$. On page 21 of Papoulis (Probability,Random Variables and Stochastic Process), there is an equation:

> $P(A) = P(B) = P(AB)$

Now using this equation one conclusion has been derived that "If an event $N$ equals the impossible event with probability $1$ then $P(N)=0$. This does not, of course, mean that $N=\phi$

Now my question why is $N$ not equal to $\phi$ ?

---

*Papoulis, A.*, Probability, random variables, and stochastic processes, New York: McGraw-Hill, XI, 583 p. (1965). [ZBL0191.46704](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.46704).

Comment: What is "phi"${}$?

Comment: I think "phi" means the empty set.

Comment: I would be curious to read how the OP understands the hypothesis that "an event A equals an event B with probability 1". I can think of a translation of this rather bizarre assertion into solid mathematics, but somehow, I doubt anyone asking the present question can reach it easily... Although I would love to be proven wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically asking: If an event $N$ has probability 0, then why can't we conclude that $N = \{\varnothing\}$? Now, note that $\{\varnothing\} \not= \varnothing$. In other words, $\{\varnothing\}$ is $\underline{not}$ the empty set. (I think that you probability meant to ask why we can't conclude that $N = \varnothing$.)

Anyhow, one of the three axioms of probability states:

$P(\varnothing) = 0$,

however, it does not state that $P(A) = 0 \Leftrightarrow A = \varnothing$.